# MultiProcessing:- Setting up two timers that will Run simultaneously and resetting it

Tags: python

I'm up to a project that will set two timers at the same time and both will run simultaneously. My program runs quite well(except for the output where the second flickers because of two simultaneous timer). I want to set a function it that will reset both of the two timers when satisfied a proper constraint. But I am struggling about how to define the function so that I can accomplish my task. If you run the code you will see that the second is flickering by nearest digits between somewhere. Please tell me the reason for it and how to prevent it.

Here's my python code:-

```
import time
import multiprocessing

# getting the starting time when the programs starts to run  
start = time.perf_counter()

# Timer function
def countdown(u):
    while u:
        mins, sec = divmod(u, 60)
        timer = '{:02d}:{:02d}'.format(mins, sec)
        print(timer, end = '\r')
        time.sleep(1)
        u -= 1

# A list where all the processes will be stored
processes = []

# Creating a main fucntion where the the processes will be initialized and run simultaneously
if __name__ == '__main__':
    p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=countdown, args=[10])
    p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=countdown, args=[11])

    p1.start()
    p2.start()

    processes.append(p1)
    processes.append(p2)

    p1.join()
    p2.join()

# getting the finisihing time when all the process ends
finish = time.perf_counter()

# printing the time taken to perform the task
print(f"The entire process ended in {round(finish-start, 2)} seconds.")
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. We don't provide debugging services. The following references give advice on debugging your code. [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/), [Six Debugging Techniques for Python Programmers](https://medium.com/techtofreedom/six-debugging-techniques-for-python-programmers-cb25a4baaf4b)  or [Ultimate Guide to Python Debugging](https://towardsdatascience.com/ultimate-guide-to-python-debugging-854dea731e1b)

Comment: to put code then use ``` (`backticks`) instead of '''

Comment: `print(timer, end = '\r')` runs two commands `sys.stdout.write(timer)` and later `sys.stdout.write('\r')` and other process may write own text between these commands - better send it as single string `print(f'{timer}\r', end='')`

Comment: maybe you should use `queue` to send both values to one process - and this process should display both values as single string -  `print(f'{timer1} {timer2}\r', end='')` - and you will see both.

Comment: some terminals may use special codes in text to move coursor in any place on screen - and you could use it to display values always in the same places on screen. And this method use modules like `course` or [Textualize](https://github.com/Textualize/textual)